# limit buttons displayed per line to 10

Tags: html, button, dynamic, jstl

I'm displaying 40 buttons using forEach , but all the buttons are displayed in one row.
I wanted to print 10 buttons per line.

Here's the sample code.

```
<c:forEach var="loop" begin="1" end="40">
<c:choose>
  <c:when test='${fn:contains(list, loop)}'>
<input type="button" value="${loop}" disabled="disabled" />
 </c:when> 
  <c:otherwise>
       <input type="button" value="${loop}"  >
    </c:otherwise> 
</c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Learn about CSS and take different screen sizes in consideration

Answer (score 0):

By using a grid in css.

For the columns you'll want to use 10 times auto (or 1fr), to divide it up into 10 colmuns of auto size (so basically equally divided among them in this case). The column and row gaps don't contribute to the solution, but are there for clearer visibility.

```css
.button-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 7px;
  grid-row-gap: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
 <input type="button">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You , It's working.